# Anyone can let me know the following syntax in C++?

Tags: c++

Why we can access `value_type` by `myType::value_type`, any c++ reference talk about it?

```
class myType{ 
public:
   typedef double value_type; // the type for elements in the array
   private:
};
```

Comment: What don't you understand. It's just a typedef.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `value_type` is a member of `myType`.  It's a name, and
name lookup says that it will be found in `myType`.  Whether the name
resolves to a `typedef`, a variable, a function, or whatever can't 
influence name lookup, since you have to find the name first, to know
what it means.  (This is a simplification, and there are cases where the
type affects lookup; where depending on the type of symbol found in a
first lookup, a second lookup might occur.)